# Масштабирование шрифтов на мобильных устройствах

Tags: css, веб-программирование

Делаю сайт, и столкнулся с такой проблемой: шрифты в разных элементах страницы при открытии страницы на мобильном устройстве масштабируются по разному.

Страница на мониторе компьютера:

[image: пример страницы на экране монитора компьютера]

Страница на эмуляторе телефона (проверял на реальном, то же самое):

[image: Страница на эмуляторе телефона]

Текст "Наша компания готова предложить..." имеет размер шрифта `font-size: 1em;`, кнопки "Наши услуги" и "Каталог картриджей" так же `font-size: 1em;` (кстати, у кнопок стоит свойство `display: inline-block`), однако отображаются они по-разному.

В `meta` тегах ничего не ставил.

Что сделать, что бы размер шрифта кнопок на мобильных устройствах менялся, как у обычного блока текста?

PS: то же самое со всеми элементами на странице, которые имеют в родителях блок со свойством `display: inline-block` .

Сайт [тут](http://d91302nl.beget.tech/)

Comment: `text-size-adjust:100%` пробовали?

Comment: @Cheg, нет, не помогло

Comment: его нужно применить к `body` + добавить префиксы `-webkit-`, `-moz-` и `-m-`

Comment: размер текста конкретного блока мало о чем говорит, если задан в `em`, надо копать в сторону того, какие "внешние блоки" имеют переопределения размеров шрифта.

Comment: @MedvedevDev, из всех внешних блоков размер шрифта указан только для тега `body` - это одинаково и для кнопок, и для текста (к слову, структура такая: `<p>текст</p><div (центрирует кнопки)>кнопки</div>`)

Comment: @Павел, без разметки и стилей тут можно только гадать ...

Comment: @MedvedevDev, добавил ссылку на сайт + некоторые уточнения: "то же самое со всеми элементами на странице, которые имеют в родителях блок со свойством display: inline-block."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

добавьте в `head`

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
```

Без этого мета тега браузер пытается масштабировать вашу страницу под размеры мобильного устройства и подстроить размер шрифта (при чем для разных элементов по разному).